# Referring to a cell in a formula, but wanting to use the cell reference in that cell, not that actual cell itself

Tags: excel-formula

I want to make it so I can build a count formula in one sheet that I can just drag down.

the cells being counted are on a different sheet.

```
Start   Ref Date
    29-Mar
19-Dec  37
21-Jan  29
28-Feb  14
```

Essentially what is happening here is that the numbers that are NOT dates are the counted cells between the Ref Date and the Start (what I am tracking doesn't follow a calendar so I can't just subtract the start from the ref date).

I hard coded the count formula to get each of the number of days between ref and start.  I'm lazy.  I want to make it so the count refers to the referenced value in the start and ref date columns.

current forumla:

```
=COUNT('SHEET1'!FQ$1:HA$1)
```

Desired Forumla:
`=COUNT($B3:$B$2)` where B3 is the referred to start taken from Sheet 1 and B2 is the ref date taken from Sheet 1.  That way I only have to change B2 in order to update the count.

How can I refer to a specific value in a cell that is taken from a different sheet???

Comment: so in sheet2, column B is just a list of dates stored as text and non dates are a number, and you want to count the numbers between two reference cells?

Comment: Hi!  Sheet2 the dates are saved as Dates, so they act as numbers.  Excel can add and subtract them.  The problem is that the courses I am tracking work off of a 168 day working calendar instead of a 365 day calendar, so I have to account for the missed days.  Essentially, if I want to find out the number of days between 2 dates, I can't just subtract them I have to count the number of cells.

Comment: are you dates in sheet 2 in multiple adjacent columns?  Are they sorted chronologically?

Comment: horizontally in a single row:

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes the dates to count are layed out as below on sheet2:

[image: Sheet 2 Data]

Lay out your start and reference dates similar to the following:

[image: Sheet 1 layout]

In cell D3 from the above example, use the following formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$C$3:$J$3,">="&Sheet1!B4,Sheet2!$C$3:$J$3,"<="&Sheet1!C4)
```

That formula can be copied down as required to match your entries for start and reference dates.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help so far.  I'm not sure excel itself can do everything I want it to.  I ended up taking an online course in macro's and VBA for Excel.